# Cheat sheet for various Mathematic topics

Tags: reference-request

I was searching through the web to find out any webpage which contains the consolidated list for all mathematical cheat sheets in various topics in one place. I couldnt find one. It would be good if we can share the known cheat sheet links in this post for various mathematical topics.

Comment: what do you mean be cheat sheets? Lists of Identities?

Comment: I think you may be looking for something like this:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46775/compendiums-of-elementary-mathematical-truths Unfortunately, there haven't been any really good answers to the question so such may not exist.

Comment: @Holdsworth88 I mean, the cheatsheets shoud contain the basic definition, formulas, its properties etc... and also some important therorem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/cheat_table.aspx) will be your best bet. I have been using it for years.

Comment: No cheat sheet for the classification of finite simple groups? My prof says I can only bring in one 8½×11 sheet to the exam.

Comment: @MarkDominus Paul's Online Notes doesn't mention groups at all if I recall. After a quick Google search, I didn't really find a cheat sheet for the classification of finite simple groups either. The website I suggested seems to contain the most consolidated cheat sheets spanning from Algebra I to DE - obviously some things are left out - math spans over many topics!

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll get some LaTeX formatted math cheat sheets http://thinkprime.wordpress.com/

~Arif